# Challenge with AWS multipart upload API: Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am building a XML string while reading a parquet file in Java. That xml string needs to get uploaded to S3 bucket.

The parquet file can have up to 2 million records.

One way to upload the XML file to S3 is by using the multipart upload API of AWS in the following way:

Once the XML string is built, convert that string to inputstream and use it in the UploadPartRequest object to call the s3Client.uploadPart() method.

Referred:

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html
2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

The code will look something like this:

```
long partSize = 5242880L;
 AmazonS3 s3Client = (AmazonS3)((AmazonS3ClientBuilder)AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(clientRegion)).build(); 
List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList();
long filePosition = 0L;

        for(int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; ++i) {
            partSize = Math.min(partSize, contentLength - filePosition);
            DLFUtil.logInfo(" Part Size - " + partSize);
            UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = (new UploadPartRequest()).withBucketName(objectDetails.getBucketName()).withKey(objectDetails.getS3Key()).withUploadId(objectDetails.getUploadId()).withPartNumber(i).withInputStream(body).withPartSize(partSize);
            UploadPartResult uploadResult = s3Client.uploadPart(uploadRequest);
            DLFUtil.logInfo("Uploaded Part " + i);
            partETags.add(uploadResult.getPartETag());
            filePosition += partSize;
            DLFUtil.logInfo("filePosition " + filePosition);
        }

        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest compRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest(objectDetails.getBucketName(), objectDetails.getS3Key(), objectDetails.getUploadId(), partETags);
        s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(compRequest);
```

The challenge is that since the parquet file can have 2 million records, when the xml string is built, it will be one huge string in memory (the string size can end up in GBs). In order to avoid having one huge string in memory, I thought of the building the string in chunks --> when the size of the string exceeds lets say 10 MB, I would like to take that chunk and do a multipart upload. Then build the next chunk and again do a multipart upload for that with the same uploadId. This would allow to have only a small part of the string in memory at a time.

However, with this I run into the error: "Your proposed upload is smaller than the minimum allowed size"

The reason why I am getting this error is because when I do a multipart upload of a chunk of the string, the last part will be less than 5 MB. For the second multipart upload of another chunk, there will again be the last part less than 5 MB. When AWS tries to assemble all the parts with completeMultipartUpload(), it expects only one part to be less than 5 MB because in typical cases, the inputstream will have the whole string or file and only last part will be less than 5 MB.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to upload the xml string without having to have the whole string in memory at a time. Let me know if there are any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I chatted with the AWS Support and they informed that that the multipart upload API is designed in such a way that it can only accept one last part less than 5 MB. Therefore, we need to upload the parts such that it meets those requirements.

In order to fix the issue, what we did is - whenever the remaining part size was less than 5 MB, we converted the inputstream back to string and returned the string back. The function building the string would receive that string and would continue to build the string further from there.

For example,
Let us assume that the whole string is going to be around 701 MB. Also lets say that we have a function buildString() which builds the string that needs to be uploaded. The function starts building the string from scratch and when the string crosses 100 MB, we do a multipart upload for that string (AWS recommends to upload an object in multiparts if the object is going to be more than 100 MB). Lets say the built string is 101 MB and we do multipart upload for that string. The multipart upload API of AWS expects that the multipart object should be uploaded in parts of 5 MB. Therefore, for the 101 MB string, 20 parts of 5 MB will get uploaded and for the remaining 1 MB - instead of uploading that, we will convert it back to string and send it back to the buildString() function.  The buildString() will take that string and continue to build the string from there. When the string length again crosses 100 MB, the same steps will be repeated. That way, every part that gets uploaded will be of exactly 5 MB. The only remaining piece of this puzzle is that right in the end when the buildString() is done building the string and uploads the remaining string, we do not need to return the string less than 5 MB. Instead that should get uploaded as that is indeed the last part of the 701 MB string which would be less than 5 MB.

The following table gives a better idea:
[Table showing string length with every multipart upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKxPj.png)

With this solution, the method to upload the multipart would like this:

```
public String uploadMultipart(boolean isLastPart, InputStream body, long contentLength) throws IOException {
        long partSize = 5242880L;

        long filePosition = 0L;

        String remainderString = null;
        int i;
        for (i = partNumber; filePosition < contentLength; ++i) {

            if ((contentLength - filePosition) < partSize && !isLastPart) {

                /**
                 * Do not publish the part which is less than 5 MB. Instead, convert it to string and return it back.
                 * The reason for that is - AWS only wants one last part to be less than 5 MB.
                 * However, with our custom-built solution to upload the parts while building the string, we would end up with multiple parts less than 5 MB.
                 * To avoid that, we will not publish the part which is less than 5 MB. We will return the string and continue building the string from there.
                 * Only if isLastPart is true (which indicates that we have completed building the string), we will not return the remaining string and rather upload it as
                 * that will indeed be the last part less than 5 MB as expected by AWS.
                 */
                remainderString = getStringFromInputStream(body);
                break;

            } else {

                partSize = Math.min(partSize, (contentLength - filePosition));

                UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = (new UploadPartRequest()).withBucketName(getBucketName()).withKey(getS3Key()).
                        withUploadId(getUploadId()).withPartNumber(i).withInputStream(body).withPartSize(partSize);
                UploadPartResult uploadResult = s3Client.uploadPart(uploadRequest);
                partETags.add(uploadResult.getPartETag());
                filePosition += partSize;
            }
        }
        partNumber = i;
        return remainderString;
    }
```

Note that the bucket name, S3 key and the upload Id set in the UploadPartRequest object should be the same for every multipart upload in this case. Only then AWS would know that these parts are associated with the same object and it would eventually assemble them together to have our single 701 MB object when we call AWS's completeMultipartUpload() function in the end.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CompleteMultipartUpload.html